# Bootstrap Modal Window And Include Javascript Files More Then Once Failed

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, include, modal-dialog

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap in my site. I want to show modal loaded content to user.

Modal window's content loading with ajax request.

I'm including javascript file with src attribute. When first load of modal dialog, everything seems ok but when second load of modal dialog, content is loading but javascript file isn't loading.

When modal window hidden i'm clearing all of it's content.

What my i do for load javascript file more than once and fire it's functions?

Answer (score 1):

**Deleted because it doesn't apply:**

<del>This is just a callback provided by bootstrap. There are 5 different callbacks:</del>

<del>**show.bs.modal:** This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.</del>

<del>**shown.bs.modal:** This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user.</del>

<del>**hide.bs.modal:** This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.</del>

<del>**hidden.bs.modal:** This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user.</del>

<del>**loaded.bs.modal:** This event is fired when the modal has loaded content using the remote option.</del>

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    yourFunction();
})
```

<del>For more information on modal just go here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals</del>

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.

Comment: This isn't solution for me. You are writing a new function in modal or in parent caller function. But i want to include javascript file in modal window's code.

Comment: @MERTDOGAN If possible, restructure your code so you don't need to do that in the first place, since it tends to be a little tricky.

Comment: @MERTDOGAN I didn't understand the question then. Are you loading a script tag <script>? maybe check if you are loading it 2 times the second time.

Comment: I don't know how can i explain my problem more simple